# How to stop the camera movie player stop playing the captured video after selecting to use it?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hi this is what I am trying to do:

1. open Camera
2. capture a new video
3. use it
4. create a MPMoviePlayerController to get the thumbnail and duration of the selected video.

All the above steps work FINE if I don't play the new video after capturing it in the Camera, however as soon as I play the video in the camera movie player, and while the video is being played then I click on 'Use' button, it will crash my app in the area of where I try to create a MPMoviePlayerController to get the thumbnail and duration of the selected video.  I believe you cannot have more than 1 instance of movie player running.

Anyone got any idea how to fix this?